# Scrolling in between text search results from a chat conversation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on chatting component of an application and one of the intended functionality that I want to provide is to search through chat messages. So far, I have been able to provide a search function that finds and highlights (assigning a span element with CSS) matching results from a chat conversation. I would like to enhance this further by providing an option that allows user to switch between multiple occurrences of the search text in the chat conversation (much like how google chrome searches for text in a web page). The following is what I have done so far.
[image]

When using search, the elements in the web page are enclosed within a span tag with a class used for highlighting the corresponding matching texts. The HTML code that is generated after finding search entries is as -
[image]

(corresponding to the search entry "he"). What I would like to do now is if it's possible to scroll/switch between each of these search results.

Thanks!

Comment: Check [`Element#scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Saad Amir mentioned you can use scrollIntoView function for this purpose. But there is a some modification to do. The thing is you have to use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead of `document.getElementById` because of you are using class name to identify the search results.

```
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('sample');
let currentIdx = -1;

const next = () => {
    currentIdx = currentIdx + 1 > elems.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIdx + 1;
    elems[currentIdx].scrollIntoView();
}

const previous = () => {
    currentIdx = currentIdx - 1 < 0 ? elems.length - 1 : currentIdx - 1;
    elems[currentIdx].scrollIntoView();
}
```

or

```
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('sample');
let currentIdx = -1;

function next() {
    currentIdx = currentIdx + 1 > elems.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIdx + 1;
    elems[currentIdx].scrollIntoView();
}

function previous() {
    currentIdx = currentIdx - 1 < 0 ? elems.length - 1 : currentIdx - 1;
    elems[currentIdx].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollIntoView function. Like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someElementId');
element.scrollIntoView();
```